# A subdomain to specific action

Tags: symfony, routes, subdomain

I have un BIG problem whit this...

I have a a SiteManager and a Listener for manage dynamics subdomains, well, the question is, how to make for redirect a subdomain to specific action in a controller, and I can't use .htacces because the server use ngix and all this will lost sense...

my sitemanager:

```
<?php

namespace Aacp\aBundle\Site;

class SiteManager
{
    private $currentSite;

    public function getCurrentSite()
    {
        return $this->currentSite;
    }

    public function setCurrentSite($currentSite)
    {

        $this->currentSite = $currentSite;
    }
}
```

my listener

```
<?php

namespace Aacp\aBundle\EventListener;

use Aacp\aBundle\Site\SiteManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class CurrentSiteListener
{
    private $siteManager;
    private $em;
    private $baseHost;

    public function __construct(SiteManager $siteManager, EntityManager $em,
                                $baseHost)
    {
        $this->siteManager = $siteManager;
        $this->em          = $em;
        $this->baseHost    = $baseHost;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $currentHost = $request->getHttpHost();
        $subdomain   = str_replace('.'.$this->baseHost, '', $currentHost);

        //redirect NO-www to wwww
        if($subdomain==$this->baseHost){
            header("Location: http://www.".$this->baseHost);
            exit;
        }

        //Looking subdomains from categories
        $site = $this->em
            ->getRepository('AacpaBundle:Category')
            ->findOneBy(array('subdomain' => $subdomain))
        ;

        //if no found subdomain make execption
        if(!$site){
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf(
                'No site for host "%s", subdomain "%s"', $this->baseHost,
                $subdomain
            ));

        }

        $this->siteManager->setCurrentSite($site);
    }
}
```

well, all this works fine, but the problem is that ALWAYS go to home action and I have 3 subdomain www, sub1, sub2, so www go homeAction(), sub1 go sub1Action(), and sub2 go sub2Action().

routing.yml

```
home:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AacpEncoderBundle:Default:home }
    host: www.%base_host% #static

sb1:
    path:   /
    defaults:   { _controller: AacpaBundle:Default:sub1 }
    host: sub1.%base_host% #static



sb2:
    path:   /
    defaults:   { _controller: AacpaBundle:Default:sub2 }
    host: sub2.%base_host% #static
```

So, I need drop rhis line for make dynamyc and take the subdomain from category entity

Help please !!! I'm crayz whit this... :(

Comment: If it's always going to www, then it's an issue in the if statement checking if $subdomain == $this->baseHost. Have you tried doing a var_dump of both variables just before that if statement to see what the values are and why it's always running? Also, I would personally opt for parse_url instead of your str_replace function

Comment: the problem is that it's works if I add Host option in routing.yml... but the subdomain is static... and if I drop this option only take the first routes...

Comment: Can you show your routing file? And what does 'subdomain is static mean'?